# How can I secure the content of my Windows laptop in case it is stolen?

Tags: disk-encryption, windows-10

I will be receiving a new Windows 10 Dell laptop tomorrow, that I will be using for work.  We are a small company, and don't have a central IT function.  I would like to secure the laptop such that no-one can access its contents if I lose it, or it's stolen.  I'm thinking of whole disk encryption or similar - what is the simplest way of going about this?

Answer (score 5):

[Windows 10 Home has Full Disk Encryption built in](https://superuser.com/questions/958418/how-do-i-switch-on-device-encryption-under-windows-10-home).
This is more than enough to protect your data from theft.
If you’re worried about the NSA, you may want to use a different encryption solution like [VeraCrypt.](http://www.top-windows-tutorials.com/disk-encryption/)

Win10 professional also has [BitLocker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/e7d75dd2-29c2-16ac-f03d-20cfdf54202f/turn-on-device-encryption) built in, a more powerful encryption solution than de Home version default. But this sends your recovery keys to the microsoft server. Very convenient but maybe less private.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest VeraCrypt's full disk encryption.

Check out their [Wiki for more information](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=System%20Encryption). Please make sure you create a rescue disk and store that somewhere secure in a safe.

Comment: VeraCrypt is a fork from the well know TrueCrypt. So even if it is *recent* as a security tool, it uses all TrueCrypt history including all the security tests and user reports from its ancestor.